# WebApi best practice for handling error codes (but not quite errors)

Tags: asp.net-web-api

What is best practice for handling errors, but they are not errors, just not-common state of some object. Imagine we have objects `Task` which is quite big and has some sensitive data inside. WebApi call `api/Tasks/123` will get this data, but some other cases should be handled, like:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
{
  var task = GetItFromDB(id);

  if (task == null) {
    return Ok(new { Error = "NOT_FOUND" });
    // or this is better?
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
  }

  // imagine I can see task only 30 minutes before they start
  if (task.StartDate.AddMinutes(-30) > DateTime.UtcNow) {
    return Ok(new { Error = "TOO_EARLY" });
    // or this is better?
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NotFound); // there is no any HTTP status code for "custom errors"
  }

  if (task.RejectedByBigBoss == true) {
    return Ok(new { Error = "REJECTED_BY_BIG_BOSS" });
    // or what Http error code would correspond? none IMHO
  }

  // all is ok, so return task
  return Ok(task);
}
```

So in other words, I may sometimes return not an object, but some 'custom' error (which in fact is not error, but object's state).

I would go with approach of my custom errors, however I am not sure what is common, best practice?

Comment: Usually you would return Bad Request (code 400) with further content in the response as needed if it is a conflict in the business logic. Ok should be reserved for a successful action. Also Get should be reserved for read only operations, any type of modification or something that starts an action that does data manipulation should not be accessible through Get.

Comment: Hi Igor.... but the request is not "bad" at all... request is correct. Just the answer is different depending on "Task" state.